# Creating a voice command that works in all windows except one in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to creating a voice command that work in all windows except one in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

E.g. I have a voice command "Window move left" that moves the window that has the focus to the monitor on the left of the monitor where the window currently is. I want this comment to work with any Windows except on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to create a voice command that work in all windows except one in Dragon NaturallySpeaking.